# загрузка символов

Tags: c++, visual-studio, загрузка, символы

При запуске отладки в visual studio у меня никогда не загружались символы ucrtbased.dll (по крайней мере я этого не замечал)
А сейчас они стали загружать и при чём очень долго

Как отключить их загрузку или сделать её быстрее

Answer (score 3):

В настройках выставляем папку для хранения символов:

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols
```

Добавляем в "Cash symbols in this directory" любую папку.

И после этого символы будут подгружаться только 1 раз в эту папку, а потом уже будут быстр оттуда браться.